# Easing when creating a timelapse using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, timelapse

I am using FFMPEG to create timelapses from multiple images - sometimes several thousand images. I want to create an effect near the end of the timelapse where it slows down a few seconds before it reaches the end.  I've heard this referred to as "easing."  Sometimes it's done at the start of a timelapse, sometimes at the end.  Right now I am using the following to create the timelapse:

```
ffmpeg -y -r %framerate% -f image2 -i %08d.jpg -b:v 16384 -vcodec mpeg4 -an -s "1920x1080" out.mp4
```

This works as expected at the constant %framerate% - but I wonder if anyone has ever worked out the ability to specify different framerates at specific points in the output movie...

I thought about encoding separate movies (probably 3 - Normal Timelapse, Slower, slowest) and then trying to concatenate them.  I'm not sure if that's possible though.

Comment: try to generate `ffconcat` list. then add `outpoint` with increasing time: `file '991.jpg' outpoint 0.080 file '992.jpg' outpoint 0.120` etc